# Adobe Air - Update not compatible error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm trying to update an AIR 2.5 app. (Packed as Windows .exe)
This error pops up bei updating:

> Application namespace and update descriptor namespace are not
>   compatible

My .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<update xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/1.0">
<version>1.1</version>
    <url>http://www.example.com/updater/my-app.exe</url>
    <description><![CDATA[New version  
  ]]></description>
</update>
```

Can somebody tell my what I did wrong?
Thanks
Uli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit has changed since AIR 2.5. Mainly, change version to versionNumber, and add versionLabel. Here is an example from: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_update_framework.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<update xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/2.5">
    <versionNumber>0.9.2</versionNumber>
    <versionLabel>Beta 2</versionLabel>
    <url>http://localhost/updater/AIRUpdater.air</url>
    <description><![CDATA[
This version has fixes for the following knowns issues:
*First issue
*Second issue   
  ]]></description>
</update>
```

Comment: It overrides versionNumber when displaying the version to the user.  So in the above example, the user will see 'Beta 2' on the update dialog instead of '0.9.2'

Answer (score 0):

Not you are wrong, you cannot use the updater IF you package your application with native installer.

Documentation here : http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Updater.html